Cannot reset SLD password in SAP Business One: "Reset password failed!"
I cannot reset a forgotten SLD password
for Business One 9.3 PL14 (9.30.240).
I tried the following:

Go to Control Center at:
https://<server>:30010/ControlCenter/
A login prompt opens.

Click on the Forgot password? URL.
A password-reset prompt opens.

Fill in the database server,
the sa user credentials,
and the desired new SLD password.
Check and recheck the specified data paranoidally.
The dabase is accessible.
The B1 client connects
to companies on that server.

Press Reset Site Password.


A modal message appears, exclaiming:

Reset password failed!

but with zero further explanations
as to what may have gone wrong.
Nor have I found any log files
with additional details about the event.
I need help with resetting the SLD password.
